# How to dynamic change a status-bar color using palettes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I  am using of Palette for dynamic status bar background  color .  for white color the status bar color should be in TranslucentStatus and for other color should be transparent color and with set color by Palette.

```
      Glide.with(fragmentContext)
                .load(offerData.getOfferImage())
                .into(new ImageViewTarget<GlideDrawable>(imgViewOffer) {
                   @Override
                    protected void setResource(GlideDrawable resource){
                        setImage(resource);
                        extractColor(resource);
                    }
 private void setImage(GlideDrawable resource) {
                    imgViewOffer.setImageDrawable(resource.getCurrent());
                    }
private void extractColor(GlideDrawable resource) {
                        Bitmap b = ((GlideBitmapDrawable) resource.getCurrent()).getBitmap();
                        Palette p = Palette.from(b).generate();
                        int defaultColor = fragmentContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
                        int whiteColor = fragmentContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
                        int color = p.getDarkVibrantColor(defaultColor);
                        if ((whiteColor == color)) {
                            setTransparentStatusBar(false);
                        } else {
                            setTransparentStatusBar(true);
                        }
                    }
                });private void setTransparentStatusBar(boolean isCheckStatus) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window w = getActivity().getWindow();
        if (isCheckStatus) {
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        } else {
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I changed your Palette, Palette works better with `AsyncListener`.
Also, You don't need anything else.

Because Here you are extracting DOMINANT Color of the image, So  no doubt it picks the best color for you

```js
Glide.with(fragmentContext).load(offerData.getOfferImage())
  .into(new ImageViewTarget < GlideDrawable > (imgViewOffer) {
    @Override
    protected void setResource(GlideDrawable resource) {
      setImage(resource);
      extractColor(resource);
    }
    private void setImage(GlideDrawable resource) {
      imgViewOffer.setImageDrawable(resource.getCurrent());
    }
    private void extractColor(GlideDrawable resource) {
      Bitmap b = ((GlideBitmapDrawable) resource.getCurrent()).getBitmap();

      Palette.from(b).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {



          int defaultColor = fragmentContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white);

          int color = palette.getDominantColor(defaultColor);
          setTransparentStatusBar(color);


        }
      });




    }
  });



private void setTransparentStatusBar(int color) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    float lightness = Lightness(color);
    if (lightness >= 0.5) {
      getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    } else if (lightness < 0.5) {
      getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
  } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to Add the `private Float Lightness(...)...`

Comment: THANKS FOR THIS IT WORK.

Comment: No problem, I just uploaded an app,Take a look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shahin.nell.musicplayer

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna suggest another way to do this, and it's not only as good as palette but better and faster and way easier.

Write this float method at the of any activity you want, you insert a Color into it and it can give you the brightness of that color.

```
public float Lightness(int color){
    int red = Color.red(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);

    float hsl[] = new float[3];
    ColorUtils.RGBToHSL(red, green, blue, hsl);
    return hsl[2];
}
```

Now you can use this everywhere like this:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       float lightness = Lightness(YOUR_COLOR);
       if (lightness >= 0.5) {
           getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
       } else if (lightness < 0.5) {
           getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
       }
   } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
   }
```

You can use this in palette as well, like below:

```
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

        float color = Lightness(palette.getVibrantColor(Enter_A_Default_Color_Here));

        if (color >= 0.5) {
            // ---- Use Dark Color
        } else if (color < 0.5) {
            // ---- Use Light Color
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: This float can also give you amount of Green, Blue, and Redness of any color you enter

Comment: Yeah it works like charms, I'll write it for You in a minute.

Comment: Ashwani, I'll write a new answer at the bottom with your code, ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the status bar color only for api greater than 21 use the palette library for extracting the palette from image([refer this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors.html) and [Palette documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html)) and then set the status bar color using

`window.setStatusBarColor`

Comment: I have all ready use this palette library I think you don't understand my question

Comment: then you know how to get color from palette swatch

Comment: yes, please check the question code I  just attached it.

Comment: please explain in brief